# How do I use external python utility files in a Django project?

Tags: python, django

Suppose the name of my Django project is 'django_project' which contains an app named 'main', and I have created a directory called 'utilities_dir' that contains a few python files (like 'utility_1.py', 'utility_2.py' et-cetera) having the functions I want to use. Where do I place the 'utilities_dir' and how do I use those files in, say, my 'views.py' file in the 'main' app directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place utilities dir in your project root folder, add `__init__.py` file to the folder then when you want use your utilities function, just do that:

```
from utilities_dir.utility_1 import  *
from utilities_dir.utility_2 import  a_specific_function
```

Structure

```
- django_project
    - main
        - views.py
    - utilities_dir
        - __init__.py
        - utility_1.py
        - utility_2.py
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you want me to place that in the 'django_project' folder parallel with the 'main' app folder?

Comment: @vik yes, just create an empty file called `__init__.py` and place it inside your utilities dir.

Comment: @vik np :) here you can read about what exactly init.py file does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to import some files from a folder located within your django project. If the following is your directory structure

```
- django_project
    - main
        - views.py
    - utilities_dir
        - __init__.py
        - utility_1.py
        - utility_2.py
```

You simply need to do this in your `views.py`

```
from utilies_dir import utility_1, utility_2
```

and then use the functions with `utility_1.some_function()` , `utility_2.some_function()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. When I run it on my browser, I receive a message saying no such module ('utilities_dir') was found.

Comment: @vik yes, because you need add  the init file as I said in my answer

Comment: @levi I don't think so, I have a project with same structure without any `init.py` file and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @vik could you please give the stacktrace of your error?

Comment: @ArchitVerma that error its because Python can find that module because you need add init.py file.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Combining the two answers solves the issue! :)

Comment: @levi My bad. You are right. You need to add a `__init.py__` file.